# changed custom post type now $image_attributes[0]; broken

Tags: custom-post-types

i wanted to change the slug of a custom post type

so i

renamed

single-myslug.php

to

single-mynewslug.php

changed

```
                 $the_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'myslug','posts_per_page'=>8));
```

to

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'mynewslug','posts_per_page'=>8));
```

and changed

*post type in wp-admin from

myslug

to

mynewslug

now only some image thumbnails are showing up when i use

```
style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>)
```

certain images show

```
style="background-image: url()
```

some have images some dont.

http://www.mbooth.devserver2012.com/work-here/

thumbnail on some of these has dissapeared from wp-admin editor why would some just unattach themself from the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you used to change the slug in the `wp-admin`, a plugin perhaps?

But I'm not sure if your method will update existing database posts. And if it does the way it did is probably where *something* went wrong.

What **exactly** did you use to update your slug in the `wp-admin`?